# SecureErrorID with time stamp is not coming in error meassage in cognos report failure message

Tags: cognos, cognos-8, cognos-10

In cognos 10.2 i am not getting SecureErrorID with time stamp (which is pretty usefull to search errors in detail in report servers log)in error meassage in cognos report failure message, earlier when we used to use cognos 8 we used to get that term as an error message when report fails.
Anything we missed ? please suggest.

Comment: Are you getting the full error message instead?

Comment: Do you still get the full message in cogserver.log?

Comment: getting following error when report fails                           RSV-DST-0014 Unable to deliver the output of the report. See the run history details for more information. Ensure that the required services are started. Ensure that the user account is configured to distribute the output in the requested manner

Comment: earlier in cognos 8 we used to get secureErrorId and timestamp in it.and depending upon that we search into cogserver.log for more details.

Answer (score 0):

There is a capability setting for this:
`Security/Capabilities/Detailed Errors`.

You control who does or doesn't get the full error there.